# How to get every string permutation where each letter is from a different string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, permutation

I have this block of code in python3:

```
keyLetters = []
for coset in cosets:
    keyLetters.append(Counter(coset).most_common(8))
```

Where `cosets` is a list of gibberish strings, and `keyLetters` are a list of the most common letters from each string.

My goal is to get every letter combination as a series of strings from their most common letters, where each position of the string is from a different coset.

So if the top three most frequent letters from three cosets are:

```
c1 = {'D', 'K', 'M'}
c2 = {'L', 'D', 'J'}
c3 = {'Z', 'B', 'F'}
```

I need the strings:

```
s1 = 'DDF'
s2 = 'DJF'
s3 = 'ZDM'
etc
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into the functions from the `itertools` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [*product*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of all your sets. With your example:

```
import itertools

c1 = {'D', 'K', 'M'}
c2 = {'L', 'D', 'J'}
c3 = {'Z', 'B', 'F'}

for chars in itertools.product(c1, c2, c3):
    print("".join(chars))
```

Which gives:

```
DDF
DDZ
DDB
DLF
DLZ
DLB
DJF
DJZ
DJB
KDF
KDZ
KDB
KLF
KLZ
KLB
KJF
KJZ
KJB
MDF
MDZ
MDB
MLF
MLZ
MLB
MJF
MJZ
MJB
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use the product function with a list of lists of letters?

Comment: @rmayo yes! `itertools.product` ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)) takes multiple iterables that contain the elements you want to use in your product. If you have a list of lists, you just need to [unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) that list-of-lists when you pass the arguments to `itertools.product`